# ObjC: Storing a variable as reference in an array

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a debug class menu in which I pass a variable to a function and it creates buttons to adjust the variable and a label to display. I am trying to store the variables in an array like so:

```
(void)init
{
    int variableArray[10];
}

-(void)addDebugVariable:(NSString*)name value:(int*)variable
{
    variableArray[0] = variable;
}

-(void)plusButtonTapped:(CCMenuItem*)button
{
    int index = (int)[button tag];
    debugVariables[index]++;
    [debugValueLabels[index] setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", debugVariables[index]]];
}
```

I've encountered 2 problems with this method. When I press the plus button, the variable is increased by 4 instead of 1. I also cannot pass property variables to my function (eg: self.scale, self.gravity).

Is this the proper way to implement a debug class? How can I properly store a variable's address and modify it from another class when a button is pressed.

Comment: You need to provide more real codes - at least workable codes. "variableArray" is definitely not correct here.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted can't possibly work, and is too confused for anybody to be able to help you. It looks like you're only posting bits and pieces.

Your init method is defining a local variable variableArray, which will cease to exist as soon as the init routine finishes.

Then you have another method, addDebugVariable, that takes a POINTER to an int, and assigns it to index 0 of another variable that is also called variableArray. Where is THAT variableArray defined? Is it an instance variable of your class? And if you want to assign an integer value to it, you should use code like this:

```
variableArray[0] = *variable;
```

The method addDebugVariable takes a string which you never do anything with. What's it for?

Then in your third method, plusButtonTapped, alters yet another array variable debugVariables, which you never mentioned. You say the value increases by 4. That usually means you're dealing with a pointer variable rather than a scalar variable. How is debugVariables declared?

Finally, in plusButtonTapped, you're using "%f" in a format string. That's for floats. I thought you were dealing with arrays of integers?